# Waiting for focus using predicate on XCUIElement

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I'm currently using NSPredicate to wait for conditions on XCUITest elements, as follows:

```
class func waitForCondition(condition: String, element: XCUIElement) -> Bool {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: condition)
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: predicate, object: element)
    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
    return result == .completed
}
```

It works for most attributes, like "exists == 1", "isSelected == 1", "isHittable == 1", etc.
But what I want is a way to check for focus and there doesn't seem to be a condition that would validate that.

To be honest, I can't find a way to check for focus even in Xcode's autocomplete. I found the documentation for XCUIElementAttributes, an interface which is adopted by XCUIElement class: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes
and it states the existence of the "hasFocus" Bool. But it really doesn't seem to exist outside of the documentation world.

I'm using Xcode 9.4.1, for the record.

Comment: wait(for: [expectation(for: NSPredicate(format: "hasKeyboardFocus == true"), evaluatedWith: yourField, handler: nil)], timeout: 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension for XCUIElement. Something like:

```
extension XCUIElement { 

    var hasFocus: Bool {
        return self.value(forKey: "hasKeyboardFocus") as? Bool ?? false
    }

}
```

This will return true/false.
You can use it like this:

```
if element.hasFocus == false {
    element.tap()
}
```